# Insert Link from table to mail (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to send Email from my ASP.NET MVC website

I write this method on my controller

```
public ActionResult SendEmail(SmartSolutions.Models.InvitationMail _objModelMail)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var emailList = db.InvitationMails.Select(model => model.To);
        var emails = String.Join(",", emailList);
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(emails);
        mail.From = new MailAddress(_objModelMail.From = "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com");
        mail.Subject = _objModelMail.Subject = "Видео интервью";

        string Body = _objModelMail.Body = "Предлагаем пройти интервью";
        mail.Body = Body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
        ("xxxxxxxx@gmail.com", "*********************");// Enter seders User name and password
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(mail);
        return View("SendEmail", _objModelMail as IEnumerable<InvitationMail>);
    }
     else
     {
         return View();
     }
}
```

But when I try to write like this `string Body = _objModelMail.Body = "Предлагаем пройти интервью" + __objModelMail.Link;`

Link not pasting to Body.

In table Link is filled.

Where is my problem?

Comment: You should probably go change your gmail password **IMMEDIATELY**

Comment: Does it compile? 

`string Body = _objModelMail.Body = "Предлагаем пройти интервью" + __objModelMail.Link;` __objModelMail.Link has an extra underscore

Comment: Yes, it compiles@Mvarta

Answer (score 0):

I found solution

Here is code

```
  public ActionResult SendEmail(SmartSolutions.Models.InvitationMail _objModelMail)
    {


         if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var emailList = db.InvitationMails.Select(model => model.To);
            var emailList2 = db.InvitationMails.Select(model => model.Link);
            var link2 = emailList2.FirstOrDefault();
            var emails = String.Join(",", emailList);
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add(emails);
            mail.From = new MailAddress(_objModelMail.From = "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com");
            mail.Subject = _objModelMail.Subject = "Видео интервью";

            string Body = _objModelMail.Body= "Предлагаем пройти интервью"+ link2;

            mail.Body = Body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
            ("xxxxxxxx@gmail.com", "********");// Enter senders User name and password
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(mail);
            return View("SendEmail", _objModelMail as IEnumerable<InvitationMail>);
        }
         else
         {
             return View();
         }
    }
```